# File load and adding to list

Tags: c#

I'm basically trying to add the items from a .txt file into a `listbox`. The problem is that the method for loading the .txt file is in a seperate class, so I came to a point where i don`t know what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the class, with the file loading method:

```
public class BunchOfDeliverables
{
    private List<Person> myPersons;
    private List<Deliverable> myDeliverables;

    public BunchOfDeliverables()
    {
        this.myPersons = new List<Person>();
        this.myDeliverables = new List<Deliverable>();
    }

    public List<Person> Persons { get { return this.myPersons; } }
    public List<Deliverable> Deliverables { get { return this.myDeliverables; } }

    public void LoadPersonsFromFile(String filename)
    {
        StreamReader sr = null;
        try
        {
            sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
            String name, street, housenr, postalcode, city;
            name = sr.ReadLine();
            while (name != null)
            {
                street = sr.ReadLine();
                housenr = sr.ReadLine();
                postalcode = sr.ReadLine();
                city = sr.ReadLine();
                this.myPersons.Add(new Person(name, street, Convert.ToInt32(housenr), postalcode, city));
                name = sr.ReadLine();
                name = sr.ReadLine(); //and again read a line, because of the delimiter (line with the stars)
            }
        }
        catch (IOException) { }
        finally
        {
            if (sr != null) sr.Close();
        }
    }

    public void LoadDeliverablesFromFile(String filename)
    {
        StreamReader sr = null;
        try
        {
            sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
            String s;
            s = sr.ReadLine();
            while (s != null)
            {
                String[] items = s.Split();
                this.myDeliverables.Add(new Deliverable(Convert.ToInt32(items[0]), Convert.ToInt32(items[1]), this.myPersons[Convert.ToInt32(items[2])]));
                s = sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException) { }
        finally
        {
            if (sr != null) sr.Close();
        }
    }


    public void AddPerson(Person p)
    {
        this.myPersons.Add(p);
    }


    public Deliverable FindDeliverable(int id)
    {
        foreach (Deliverable d in this.myDeliverables)
        {
            if (d.ID == id)
            {
                return d;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void AddDeliverable(Deliverable d)
    {
        if (FindDeliverable(d.ID) == null)
        {
            myDeliverables.Add(d);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Be aware: nothing is added!!!");
        }

    }
```

AND then here is the form class (mostly empty):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BunchOfDeliverables d;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        d = new BunchOfDeliverables();
    }

    private void AddLoadedFilesToListbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }


Edit :
```

I tryed the following but again it does not work:

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BunchOfDeliverables d;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            d = new BunchOfDeliverables();
            d.LoadDeliverablesFromFile("..data/deliverables.txt");
        }

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (Deliverable deliv in d.Deliverables)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(deliv);
        }

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Which part doesn't work?

Comment: You are missing a call to `BunchOfDeliverables.LoadPersonsFromFile(String filename)`. In your sample code, somewhere you must call `d.LoadPersonsFromFile("your filename goes here")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is that simple:

```
BunchOfDeliverables bunchOfDeliverables = new BunchOfDeliverables();
bunchOfDeliverables.LoadPersonsFromFile(personsFile);
bunchOfDeliverables.LoadDeliverablesFromFile(deliverablesFile);

listBox.DataSource = bunchOfDeliverables.Persons;
listBox.DisplayMember = "<Whatever>";
listBox.ValueMember = "<Whatever>";

// OR
listBox.DataSource = bunchOfDeliverables.Deliverables;
listBox.DisplayMember = "<Whatever>";
listBox.ValueMember = "<Whatever>";
```

I don't know which list (`Persons` or `Deliverables`) do you use, so the code contains both.

Comment: @KonstantinHadzhiev Your're welcome. If this solves your problem, please mark the answer as accepted.